# OpenUI5: Issue with adding a view to an element

Tags: view, sapui5

I try to include an HTML-View in a XML-View which actually shouldn't be a problem. Unfortunately the content of the HTML-View is not added to the site. An error is not thrown.

In the XML-View I have a placeholder for the HTML-View:

```
<html:div
    id="helptext">
</html:div>
```

In the controller of the XML-View I instantiate the HTML-View and add it to the placeholder:

```
var oController = sap.ui.controller("dividendgrowthtools.view.textviews.dividendcomparehelpDE");
var oTextView = sap.ui.view({ 
                    viewName: "dividendgrowthtools.view.textviews.dividendcomparehelpDE",
                    controller: oController,
                    type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.HTML
                });

var oHelpText = this.getView().byId("helptext");
oTextView.placeAt(oHelpTextDiv.sId);
```

That's the content of the HTML-View:

```
<template data-controller-name="dividendgrowthtools.view.textviews.dividendcomparehelpDE">
    <p>This is a test.</p>
</template>
```

Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Is a nested view an option? No need for extra JS code. Just replace your placeholder with an include of your html view https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/df8c9c3d79b54c928855162bafcd88ee.html

Comment: Unfortunately not as I need to have the possibility to include different views at the placeholder...

Comment: I'm lowering the question score since HTML views are deprecated by now: [`ef39784`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/ef397849ae0423ad758ca25ac45a16aa18afc789), [`2f98d40`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/2f98d407cd3752e6dcf1fc6e7938202c5db183cf)

Answer (score 0):

you need to be aware of the functionality of this.getView().byId();
SAPUI5 generates another ID then the one you specified in the XML-View("helptext") see: [image: Screenshot of the generated HTML by SAPUI5]
So you need to pass the right ID. You need to be aware that these ID could possibily change, when you refactor the XML structure.

I would recommend you, not to use HTML elements in SAPUI5.

Some helpful links:

- https://scn.sap.com/thread/3551589
- https://plnkr.co/edit/wDBpQuxIWd0WGOoyulN0?p=preview (made by me)`PLnkr Link`

Comment: I'm aware of this fact. That's why I use

    "oHelpTextDiv.sId"

when I reference the div. However, it does not work - the HTML view is not included in the DOM and no error is thrown... I also tried it with an SAPUI5 component instead of the div. But it does not work either.